# Binding image from SQL Server to repeater in ASP.NET not loading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web, webforms

I want to bind image from SQL Server to repeater in ASP.NET, the image is not loading here is my codes when binding the image in not loading can someone help please?

[image]

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepterDetails" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>Products View</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title") %>' Font-Bold="true" />

        <hr />
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("img1") %>' Width="100" Height="100" AlternateText="No picture found" Visible="true" />

        <hr />

        Post By:
        <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
        Created Date:<asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%#Eval("Date") %>' />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Order Now" />
        <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>  

public void RepeterData()
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from [Products T]", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    RepterDetails.DataSource = ds;
    RepterDetails.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: did you check the urls coming from the sql table? If you manually put them in an image tag, are the pictures loading? Is there a console message on the client?

Comment: my urls comes from the table in SQL, here is my console log error: View:34 GET https://localhost:44378/Posts/System.Byte[] 404

Answer (score 0):

A byte array is not an image url. You cannot just paste it in an url and expect an image to appear.

You need to convert the byte array back to an actual image. Either by creating a Generic Handler that loads the image, or show it as base64

```
ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("img1")) %>'
```

However I would only use base64 if the images are very small and there are not a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `Bytes` via URL, before pass image to your ASP.NET control you can do this actions (I assume your image format is `jpg`) :

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("img1") %>' Width="100" Height="100" AlternateText="No picture found"  Visible="true"/>
...
public void RepeterData()
{
    ...
    var imageBinary = ds["Img1"].ReadAsBytes();
    var imageString =  Convert.ToBase64String(imageBinary , 0, imageBinary.Length);
    Image1.Src =  "data:image/jpg;base64," + imageString;
}
```